# When to use one tailed or two tailed tests for power analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, one-tailed-test

Is it ok to choose one tailed test if it is assumed that a certain drug is going to reduce metastatic tumor?

Comment: At the start, everyone involved _hopes_ that a new drug will have a desired effect in the appropriate direction. Unfortunately, some drugs actually have a contrary effect.  In most countries, trials for approval of a drug must follow protocols approved in advance by gov't agencies as to 1 or 2-sidedness and methods of analysis. So the final word on this is not up to the experimenter but up to a gov't agency. // One-sided tests typically require fewer subjects to get a given power, so it is legitimate to try getting 1-sided tests into the protocol, but there is no guarantee of approval.